# Encoding issue, coverting &amp; to & for html using php

Tags: php, character-encoding, html-entities

I have a url in html:

```
<a href="index.php?q=event&amp;id=56&amp;date=128">
```

I need to turn it into a string exactly as:

```
<a href="index.php?q=event&id=56&date=128">
```

I know how to do this with preg_replace etc, but is there a function in php that deals directly with encoding that I can use for other encoding issues such as &nsbp (or whatever it is, etc)? Ideally I would send my string into the function and it would output '&' instead of &amp. Is there a universal function for converting &TEXT; into an actual character?

Edit: sorry, posted this before I finished typing the question. QUESTION is now complete.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
$newUrl = html_entity_decode('<a href="index.php?q=event&amp;id=56&amp;date=128">');
echo $newUrl; // prints <a href="index.php?q=event&id=56&date=128">
```

Comment: Be aware of `htmL_entity_decode` and `&nbsp;`. You can replace it with `$txt = str_replace("\xA0", ' ', $txt);`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode). Example straight from the PHP documentation page:

```
$str = '<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str); // <p>this -> "</p>
```

Comment: html_entity_decode - Convert all applicable characters, htmlspecialchars_decode - Convert special characters... (from php.net)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in PHP function that will take an entity such as `&amp;` and turn it into a double &. Just in case there is any confusion, the html entity for & is actually `&amp;`, not `amp;`, so running any built in parser on your example will return the following:

```
<a href="index.php?q=event&id=56&date=128">
```

and not

```
<a href="index.php?q=event&&id=56&&date=128">
```

In order to get the double & version, you will need to use a regular expression.

Alternatively, if you in fact want the single & version, you have two possibilities.

1. If you just wish to convert `&amp; &quot; &#039; &lt; &gt;` then you should use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). This would be sufficient for the example you give.
2. If you wish to convert any string of the format &TEXT; then you should use [html_entity_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

I suspect that htmlspecialchars_decode will be faster than html_entity_decode so if it covers all the entities you wish to convert, you should use that.

Comment: +1 - thanks for the follow-up points about the differences between the two options.

Answer (score 0):

after string go through TinyMCE only this code help me

```
$string = iconv('UTF-8','cp1251',$string);
$string = str_replace(chr(160), chr(32), $string);
$string = iconv('cp1251','UTF-8',$string);
```