# How I can redirect php page with 2 variables

Tags: php

I am redirecting php page with following

```
<a href='invoice_details.php?ppid=".$row['sno']."'..
```

but I want to redirect the same with some another condition
can this be done

```
<a href='invoice_details.php?ppid=".$row['sno']." and 'invoice_details.php?pinv=".$row['invno']."'
```

Comment: Explain your question clearly with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<a href="yourscript.php?variable1=one&amp;variable2=two&amp;variable3=three">Link</a>
```

And then in php:

```
$variable1 = $_GET['variable1']; // one
$variable2 = $_GET['variable2']; // two
$variable3 = $_GET['variable3']; // three
```

---

In your example:

```
<a href='invoice_details.php?ppid=".$row['sno']."&amp;pinv=".$row['invno']."'>link</a>
```

---

Here is a little explanation about `&amp;` notation: [Encoding issue, coverting &amp; to & for html using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516949/encoding-issue-coverting-amp-to-for-html-using-php)
It is better to write html links with entity `&amp;` then simple `&`.

---

More docs on get: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php.
**Remember to run some check on your get values, and not save / post them directly on site as this can make some security issues.**

Comment: Thanks, need more help, your email

Comment: No problem. Please accept the edits on your question, and if the answer is ok, also accept it :). If you have any other problems, please create a new question. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

user amerpsand to add parameters to your url:

```
<a href='invoice_details.php?ppid=".$row['sno']."&pinv=".$row['invno']."'....
```

Comment: &amp; is much more better here... :).